# Connect SymmetricDS to ParaSQL

Tags: sql-server, ssl, sql-server-2008-r2, symmetricds

We're trying to test loading data from our on-premise SQL Server 2008R2 machine to ParaSQL using SymmetricDS. We have a dedicated server instance with ParaSQL which requires an SSL connection. Certificates are provided by ParaSQL.

Where we're stuck is how to configure SymmetricDS to use secure socket layer for this connection. We can find some info in the documentation on how to generate keys on our end, but nothing on how to connect using provided certificates.

Does anyone here have any experience with that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With SymmetricDS there is an SSL connection between the SymmetricDS nodes, and a different one between the JDBC driver and the database itself. The keys you are generating sound like they are for the node-to-node SSL. I believe what you need to do is setup the ParaSQL supplied SSL certificates for the JDBC driver that is making the connection to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you clarify a bit more how I could setup certificates for the JDBC driver? Kinda new at all this.

Comment: Try this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html